# Adding text input to a blackberrycanvas

Tags: java, blackberry

The [BlackBerryCanvas documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lcdui/BlackBerryCanvas.html) says:

> This class extends the functionality of the Canvas class to include full touch support and featured text input support.

I have extended BlackBerryCanvas, but am having trouble adding any text input.

It's not that I know what to do but cannot get it work -- I simply do not know how to add a text input box or field.

EDIT: Or have I misunderstood and this is not possible? From reading around, it seems as though it is, but I'm starting to wonder why it's so hard to find anything on it.

EDIT2: I'm think maybe it's something to do with the [BlackBerryTextBox](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lcdui/BlackBerryTextBox.html)?

EDIT3:

> Applications using this class can call the #setInputHelper method to get the text input support.

might also be something. It hasn't given me quite enough clues to be able to do it myself though I'm afraid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't particularly need to use the [Canvas](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html) hierarchy, I suggest you use the more commonly used [Field](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html) hierarchy.

That means you should create an application and start with a [Screen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html).  An easy concrete implementation of Screen is the [FullScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/FullScreen.html).  To get the text input you are seeking, add an [AutoTextEditField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/AutoTextEditField.html) to the screen.

Comment: Sorry I should have said. It's a MIDlet, which I am enhancing for the blackberry. Since I can use BlackberryCanvas rather than Canvas without having to resort to a full rewrite, I was hoping to be able to use that hierarchy.